# Java Android/Eclipse: how to get a screen with a canvas and some buttons?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm making an app for Android with Java in eclipse, and it will have multiple screens. One screen will contain a canvas with 2D graphics, and some buttons below the canvas. But I'm a newbie at Android so it's still a little messy to me. Seems like a new Paint() in a class which extends View always is fullscreen (?) so I tried to solve it with Fragments where I put the canvas/newPaint() in one Fragment and the buttons in another one. But my app crashes when I try to add the Fragments in the xml file, and I don't know why.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/game_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.tictactoe.GameFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    tools:layout="@layout/game_view" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/game_fragment2"
    android:name="com.example.tictactoe.GameFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    tools:layout="@layout/game_view" />
```

Is there any other way of getting a 2D graphics canvas together with some buttons on a screen,
or can someone help me out with the fragment solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Here's the stacktrace (all of the text marked as red)
http://txs.io/bSvb

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace gives what the error is - GameFragment is not a class inheriting from Fragment. You need to ensure that you are placing Fragment classes appropriately in your layout.

Also from looking at your layout, you are placing GameFragment layout twice in the same root view. This looks wrong on some level. I mean if you have your buttons in a different layout, shouldn't you be using that layout? Also, as a tip, inflate the layout for the fragment by overriding the GamrFragment's onCreateView() method (you should see this method once you have inherited from the Fragment class appropriately).

And last but not the least, when using Fragments, ensure that you use the right version uniformly (if you use the fragments from the support package, stick to using it uniformly).